# Penalized Regression: "ridge" RMSE greater than that for plain "lm"

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

Working with the "prostate" dataset in "ElemStatLearn" package.

```
set.seed(3434)

fit.lm = train(data=trainset, lpsa~., method = "lm")
fit.ridge = train(data=trainset, lpsa~., method = "ridge")
fit.lasso = train(data=trainset, lpsa~., method = "lasso")
```

**Comparing RMSE (for bestTune in case of ridge and lasso)**

```
fit.lm$results[,"RMSE"]
[1] 0.7895572

fit.ridge$results[fit.ridge$results[,"lambda"]==fit.ridge$bestTune$lambda,"RMSE"]
[1] 0.8231873

fit.lasso$results[fit.lasso$results[,"fraction"]==fit.lasso$bestTune$fraction,"RMSE"]
[1] 0.7779534
```

**Comparing absolute value of coefficients**

```
abs(round(fit.lm$finalModel$coefficients,2))
(Intercept)   lcavol  lweight  age    lbph    svi     lcp     gleason    pgg45
       0.43   0.58    0.61     0.02   0.14    0.74    0.21    0.03       0.01 

abs(round(predict(fit.ridge$finalModel, type = "coef", mode = "norm")$coefficients[8,],2))
              lcavol    lweight   age    lbph    svi    lcp    gleason    pgg45
              0.49      0.62      0.01   0.14    0.65   0.05   0.00       0.01

abs(round(predict(fit.lasso$finalModel, type = "coef", mode = "norm")$coefficients[8,],2))
              lcavol   lweight   age    lbph    svi    lcp    gleason   pgg45
              0.56     0.61      0.02   0.14    0.72   0.18   0.00      0.01
```

My question is: how can "ridge" RMSE be higher than that of plain "lm". Doesn't that defeat the very purpose of penalized regression vs plain "lm"?

Also, how can the absolute value of the coefficient of "lweight" be actually higher in ridge (0.62) vs that in lm (0.61)? Both coefficients are positive originally without the abs().

I was expecting ridge to perform similar to lasso, which not only reduced RMSE but also shrank the size of coefficients vs plain "lm".

Thank you!

Comment: `how can ridge RMSE be higher than that of plain lm` why do you think it shouldn't be higher?

Comment: Nod a *coding* question, better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ridge will have higher *training* error because its error term depends not only on the data, but also on the parameters. It is said that it generalizes better. This does not mean that the training error will be lower.

Comment: @Coolness - thank you for your response!

Comment: @desertnaut - thank you for directing me!